# AWS IAM - best way to revoke temporary credentials for service linked roles-ec2 service linked role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Any advice on best option for revoking temp credentials issued for ec2 service linked role.
I can prefrom a revoke session fro console/api but this revoke all temp creds for the role, is it possible to revoke cred for service link role for EC2 or is the some other way via policies that I can revoke or reduce permissions.

I also have this problem for cross-account-role it do not seem to be able to revoke the temp creds by session as above I only have the option to revoke all session for entities that have assumed the role.

For instance if I have a user that has assumed a role (I deem the activity to me suspicious) is it possible for me to revoke or reduce the user permissions without affecting other users that have assumed the role?

Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only we to revoke temp creds for specific sessions is to add the arn of the principle assume the role to the role being assumed - stating and Explicit deny.

Answer (score -1):

According to the IAM user guide:

> You cannot revoke the session for a service-linked role.

You cannot revoke a session per user either. When you revoke an active session, IAM attaches a policy  to the role that denies all actions on all resources. Consequently, all users that has assumed this role before revoking the session has to re-assume the role.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_revoke-sessions.html

Comment: Hi Vikyol, Their lies my problem. I just want to revoke the session for the entity that assume the cross-account role. Also for service linked role it states that these cannot be revoked.